# Msgbox does not close automatically

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been trying to create a messagebox, that closes automatically after a few seconds. I tried with my own code first (CommandButton1) and then used some code I found on the internet. However, none of them work. Anyone who has an idea why?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim checkDt, AbortTime As Date
Dim strAbort As String
    If Date - 365 > checkDt Then
        AbortTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Do
            MsgBox("Your License has expired! This Workbook will now close in 5sec.", vbCritical, "Expired")
            
        Loop While Now() < AbortTime
        userform1.show
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim time_set As Integer, MsgBox As Object
Set MsgBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Set the message box to close after 1 second
time_set = 2
Select Case MsgBox.PopUp("Hello There!", time_set, "Message Box will be gone after 1 Second", 0)
Case 1, -1
Exit Sub
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.PopUp "", 3, "This Message Box will be gone in 1 second"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Set the message box to close after 10 seconds
AckTime = 4
Select Case InfoBox.PopUp("Done !! Click OK " & Chr(13) & Chr(13), AckTime, "RV 7383423400", 0)
Case 1, -1
Exit Sub
End Select
End Sub
´´´´
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `MsgBox` will always block while waiting for user input (to click the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button).

I created a UserForm with three labels: `Label1`, `Label2`, and `Label3`.

[image]

Then uses the following code for the UserForm:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim timeout As Date
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 5 To 1 Step -1
        Me.Label2.Caption = CStr(i)
        Me.Repaint
        timeout = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While Now() < timeout
    Next i
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Be aware that, while this code works, the `DoEvents` must run to allow other system processes to work ***AND*** may throw off the exact timing of your countdown. The UserForm does *generally* close in about five seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the 4th example in an MS Access VBA module, and this works correctly
(I just commented out the 2 MS Excel specific lines):

```
Private Sub TestMsgBox()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'On Error Resume Next
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
    Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    
    'Set the message box to close after 10 seconds
    AckTime = 10
    
    Select Case InfoBox.PopUp("Done !! Click OK " & Chr(13) & Chr(13), AckTime, "RV 7383423400", 0)
        Case 1, -1
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Did you add a reference to the Windows Script Host object model?

Comment: I just checked and the script host object model reference has been added. Still, it doesn't work. Do I need any other references?

Comment: Actually not. As you are using late binding it should even work without the reference, now that I think about it. I tested the same routine in a blank  xlsm worksheet without any added references and it still works. I also assigned the sub "TestMsgBox" as a macro to a Shape (circle) object and it still works (needed to remove the "Private" statement for that).  Are you sure the message box is not running somewhere in the background? Do you get any error message? Are the procedures correctly assigned to your command buttons?

Comment: I got it to work now. I restarted my laptop and now it's working. Didn't change the code. Don't ask me why??? 
Before the msgbox was popping up, but nothing was happening when the time expired. Now it works though.
Thanks for your help :)